# How can I see all of the sensors that an app is using?

Tags: android, logging, root, sensors

I'm trying to compile a list of sensors each app uses on a device and track the data that each sensor is returning.

My first attempt to do so was to read logs with

```
adb logcat Senors:V AkmSensor:V SensorManager:V *:S
```

Which gives me a pretty solid list of `registerListener` and `unregisterListener` events for each sensor like so:

```
D/SensorManager(30158): registerListener :: 1600940398, Linear Acceleration Sensor, 250000, 0,  
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Disable 
D/SensorManager(30158): unregisterListener ::   
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Enable 
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Set_Delay , delay = 20
D/SensorManager(30158): registerListener :: 1600615030, Gravity Sensor, 66667, 0,  
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Enable 
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Set_Delay , delay = 66
D/AkmSensor( 2973): Magnetic_Disable 
D/SensorManager(30158): unregisterListener ::   
D/SensorManager(30158): registerListener :: 0, BMI055 Accelerometer Sensor, 250000, 0,  
D/SensorManager(30158): unregisterListener ::   
D/SensorManager(30158): registerListener :: 4, CM3323 Light Sensor, 250000, 0,  
D/SensorManager(30158): unregisterListener ::
```

but I'm not sure how to figure out which application is calling for the sensors and what values these sensors are returning to them.

Is there a better way of solving this problem? How can I see the data being collected by a sensor from outside of the application that called for it?

Note: I have root access. Is there a place where I could/should create my own logs for sensor data within the system?

Comment: Build a custom ROM. In that custom ROM, have a modified framework JAR with a modified `SensorManager` where you log your requisite information, including wrapping any `SensorEventListener` objects so you can intercept the actual sensor readings.

Comment: This sounds like a solid solution. Thank you, I'll edit my post if all goes well!